# convertPoint doesn't return the value I want

Tags: ios, swift, cgpoint

I have a view called **RulerView**, which has a subView:

**StickerImageView**

This ImageView contain the Image, and I can add movable TextView on it.

Now what I'm trying to is: Track the movement of TextView on **StickerImageView**, when the distance between the `center.y` of TextView and the `center.y` of RulerView is smaller than some value, the TextView will be moved to the center of **RulerView**.

So I guessed I need to convert the centerPoint of TextView to RulerView first

Here is what I have tried:

```
    let rulerView = self.superview as? RulerView

    let labelPoint = TextLabel.convertPoint(TextLabel.center, toView: rulerView)
```

However, the value of labelPoint wasn't what I want. Did I do something wrong? Or maybe there is a better solution? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make so: TextLabel.center = rulerView.center;